# separate results from nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, formatting

I created a nested loop.

```
import math 
results = []
for i in range(3,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        something = (i, ((math.factorial(j-1 + i-1)/ (math.factorial(i-1) * math.factorial(j-1)))))
    print something,
```

Output of this looks like this:(3, 1) (3, 3) (3, 6) (3, 10) (4, 1) (4, 4) (4, 10) (4, 20)
How could i separate the two sets of (3,x) and (4,y) from each other and print them on two different lines with writing. So the result would look something like:

3: [1,3,6,10]

4: [1,4,10,20]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the results for each `i` , then you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) , Example -

```
import math
from collections import defaultdict
results = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(3,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        results[i].append((math.factorial(j-1 + i-1)/ (math.factorial(i-1) * math.factorial(j-1))))
    print '{} : {}'.format(i,results[i])
```

Result -

```
3 : [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0]
4 : [1.0, 4.0, 10.0, 20.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just append it to a dictionary value  by using [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
import math 
results = {}
for i in range(3,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        something = (i, ((math.factorial(j-1 + i-1)/ (math.factorial(i-1) * math.factorial(j-1)))))
        results.setdefault(something[0], []).append(something[1])  #Create key if not available with default [] value if available get the value and append to the list 
print results

{3: [1, 3, 6, 10], 4: [1, 4, 10, 20]}
```